# Grails - List returns proxied classes instead of domain classes

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy

I have noticed that when calling list on domain classes in Grails, the results I am returned are proxy instances instead of the actual domain class instances.

**Example**:

```
println User.list()

[ com.mypackage.security.User_$$_javassist_28 ]
```

When comparing an instance of one of these proxy classes against the matching domain class instance, I receive a false equality result.

The Groovy "Differences from Java" documentation states:

> == means equals on all types. 
>   ...
>   So for simplicity == means equals() in Groovy

Yet when comparing a domain class to one of these proxy classes this does not seem to be true.

Can someone provide some insight on this?

Is there a way to call list and receive actual domain class instances?

I'd rather not have to provide a custom getHashCode and equals implementation just to work around this.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you override the equals() and hashCode() in the domain class?

Comment: @evanwong - No I am not overriding equals or hashCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make it to return different type using list() and the `==` return false should have nothing to do what type is returned by list.

In Java, for 2 objects of the same type to be equal, you have to implement the `equals` and `hashCode`. Groovy shares the same even you can use the `==` to test equality.

Back you your equals question.

> == means equals on all types. 
>   ...
>   So for simplicity == means equals() in Groovy

This is not the whole story.

[Here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) is a better explanation.

> In situations where two objects might be thought "equal" via normal Groovy "coercion" mechanisms, the == operator will report them as equal; the .equals() method will not do so if doing so would break the normal rules Java has around the equals method.

Now since you want to avoid the implementation, you can probably take the advantage of the Groovy AST. 
You can annotate the class with `@EqualsAndHashCode` to let that handle it for you.
[Grooydoc here.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html)